# Numerical specification in Java

Tags: java, double, java-8

Suppose in jdk 8 specification, and `x1, x2` and `y1, y2` are `int` variable, I want to know if following situations could happen:

```
mathematically x1/y1 != x2/y2 but in Java x1/(double)y1 == x2/(double)y2
mathematically x1/y1 == x2/y2 but in Java x1/(double)y1 != x2/(double)y2
```

Assuming mathematically `0/0 != 0/0` and `Inf == Inf` and `+0 == -0`

Comment: Then there's NAN, which is never equal to any double (including itself?), and +0 and -0, which are == but sort as > and < differently.  [Learn your numbers.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)  Also, in any language, floating point arithmetic is not associative.

Comment: @markspace, I know what you're saying and I've edited so that it's assumed mathematically `+0 == -0` , please provide concrete examples of `int` input `x1, y1, x2, y2` to show the contradiction.

Comment: It could certainly happen if they were `long` values, but I'm not certain if there's a case that works for `int`s.

Comment: Since the precision of `double` is known exactly, it should be easy to construct such cases by using values close to the precision limits. However, it’s not clear to me why we should do the work for you. What have *you* tried?

Comment: @Holger I've answered the question because it did not seem quite so trivial to me to find an example for the first proposition, and an argument that no example exists for the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you should specify a number system rather than the vague "mathematically". There are a lot of systems in mathematics that define division. I would have assumed you meant real number arithmetic, but it has a single zero and you seem to be permitting division by zero, which real number arithmetic does not define. I am going to assume you mean real number arithmetic for divisions not involving zero, extended in a way compatible with Java double arithmetic for divisions that do have a zero operand.

The first case can happen:

```
x1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE
y1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE-1
x2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE-1
y2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE-2
```

Both double divisions get the same answer: 1.0000000004656613

Clearly, the two divisions have different exact answers. The 40 decimal place BigDecimal results are:

```
1.0000000004656612877414201272105985574523
1.0000000004656612879582605622125704244886
```

Here is a demonstration program:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double baseDouble = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    double minus1Double = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1;
    double minus2Double = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2;
    BigDecimal baseBD = new BigDecimal(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    BigDecimal minus1BD = new BigDecimal(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1);
    BigDecimal minus2BD = new BigDecimal(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2);
    System.out.println("base " + baseDouble + " " + baseBD);
    System.out.println("minus1 " + minus1Double + " " + minus1BD);
    System.out.println("minus2 " + minus2Double + " " + minus2BD);
    System.out.println("Double base/minus1 " + baseDouble / minus1Double);
    System.out.println("Double minus1/minus2 " + minus1Double / minus2Double);
    System.out.println("BigDecimal base/minus1 "
        + baseBD.divide(minus1BD, 40, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN));
    System.out.println("BigDecimal minus1/minus2 "
        + minus1BD.divide(minus2BD, 40, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN));
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
base 2.147483647E9 2147483647
minus1 2.147483646E9 2147483646
minus2 2.147483645E9 2147483645
Double base/minus1 1.0000000004656613
Double minus1/minus2 1.0000000004656613
BigDecimal base/minus1 1.0000000004656612877414201272105985574523
BigDecimal minus1/minus2 1.0000000004656612879582605622125704244886
```

It is easy to see that the second case is impossible for divisions that do not have a zero operand.

Every `int` is exactly convertible to double, so the exact quotient of the doubles matches the exact quotient of the original values. For the definition of division, see the Java Language Specification, [15.17.2 Division Operator /](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.17.2). The process for dividing a pair of finite numbers neither of which is zero is equivalent to mapping the exact quotient into either the double value set or the double-extended-exponent value set.

Exponent overflow and underflow in `double` are impossible for the `int` range, so the two value sets will give the same answer. The rounding rules are independent of the calculation that led to the result being rounded, so two divisions of int-valued doubles that have the same exact quotient have the same rounded result.

Comment: Good explanation! Also +1 for the division operator reference.